# Как ограничить доступ по IP для FTP (vsftpd) на Cent OS?

Tags: linux, centos, ftp

Как ограничить доступ по IP для FTP (vsftpd) на Cent OS?
Нужно, чтобы только для указанных IP был доступ.
Правка `hosts.deny/allow` работает для Ubuntu, Cent OS почему-то нет.

Comment: закройте 20-21 tcp порты на уровне фаервола (iptables)

Comment: спасибо работает